# Securing Firebase realtime database granting access to Android wear devices

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, android-wear-2.0

I have a firebase realtime database that is accessed mostly by Android Wear devices running a standalone application.
As of today, [Android Wear devices do not support Firebase Authentication](https://plus.google.com/+LewisMcGeary/posts/BQzGE2G4RX6).
Yet Firebase keeps pushing me emails telling that my database has insecure rules. I have changed access rules restricting access to admin-only areas, and most probably firebase will stop sending me this kind of emails, but still the sensitive data has public read access.

Has anyone faced and solves this issue?